# VBA Saving (and converting) a Document From .docm to .docx

Tags: vba, ms-word, save, save-as

I have the following code at the end of a project:

```
'Save the Document
Dim Directory As String, FileName As String
Directory = "C:\Users\" & (Environ$("Username")) & _
    "\Desktop\STL\"
If Len(Dir(Directory, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
    MkDir Directory
End If
FileName = sDNUM & " " & Format(Date, "YYYY-MM-DD") & ".docx"
SaveAs Directory & FileName


MsgBox "File saved to:" & vbNL & Directory & FileName
```

and I am trying to get the file to save as a `docx` (non-macro enabled) after running a macro-enabled workbook.

The problem is by using the above method to save my file, upon attempting to open the newly saved file I receive the following error message:

> The file *< filename >* cannot be opened because there are problems with the contents.

What method should I use to properly save these documents?

### Miscellaneous notes for the curious:

`vbNL` is just a function for `vbNewLine`. I use it quite often and I guess I am just too lazy to type it out all the time so I made a function to shorten the text.

`sDNUM` is also just another function that is irrelevant to the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Saving the file with a `docx` extension does not automatically convert it as non-macro-enabled.

Change

```
SaveAs Directory & FileName
```

to

```
SaveAs2 Directory & FileName, wdFormatXMLDocument
```

For more information on the `SaveAs2` method, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836084.aspx).